# Log4jdbc level configuration is not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, logging, log4jdbc

This is my logback.xml configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-3level %logger{5} - %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <include resource = "org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"></include> -->

    <logger name="jdbc.sqlonly" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="jdbc.sqltiming" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="jdbc.audit" level="OFF"/>
    <logger name="jdbc.resultset" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="jdbc.resultsettable" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="jdbc.connection" level="OFF"/>

    <root level="OFF">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

As you can see, I turned the level off of audit and connection.
But I can see the audit log is keep showing.
Am I missing something or something is in bad configuration?

```
DEBUG: adminMapper.readAll - <==      Total: 5
DEBUG: jdbc.resultset - 2. ResultSet.close() returned void  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(null:-2)
DEBUG: jdbc.audit - 2. PreparedStatement.getConnection() returned net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.ConnectionSpy@31a5f9af  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(null:-2)
DEBUG: jdbc.audit - 2. Connection.getMetaData() returned com.mysql.cj.jdbc.DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema@7e246793  org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getNextResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:258)
DEBUG: jdbc.audit - 2. PreparedStatement.getMoreResults() returned false  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(null:-2)
DEBUG: jdbc.audit - 2. PreparedStatement.getUpdateCount() returned -1  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(null:-2)
DEBUG: jdbc.audit - 2. PreparedStatement.isClosed() returned false  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(null:-2)
DEBUG: jdbc.audit - 2. PreparedStatement.close() returned   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(null:-2)
DEBUG: org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3b5d92df]
DEBUG: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
INFO : jdbc.connection - 2. Connection closed  org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doCloseConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:343)
DEBUG: jdbc.connection - open connections:  none
DEBUG: jdbc.audit - 2. Connection.close() returned
```

Comment: I also tried to change my root level as info, error. 
There were some difference but none of those erased audit level log

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just commenting the line out?  I control my logging through application.properties and the following works for me:

```
# log4jdbc logging
# ================
logging.level.jdbc.sqltiming=debug
logging.level.jdbc.resultsettable=info


# other options...
logging.level.jdbc.sqlonly=debug
#logging.level.jdbc.audit=debug
#logging.level.jdbc.resultset=debug
#logging.level.jdbc.resultsettable=info
#logging.level.jdbc.connection=debug
```